# Flutter Sound: flutterSoundHelper.convertFile crash on release app

Tags: flutter, file-conversion, voice-recording

I used Flutter Sound package to make a recorder app,
On debug, my app can record, play record, convert the temp file recorded to premanent file mp3,

But on release, when the app tried to convert the file, the app crash
recording and playing recorded file work well but the conversion make the crash,

I've checked with alert dialog if file exist, and it exist, (for sure cause the file can be played); but i don't know what wrong if its a package bug or i used the wrong way.

i've already asked for issue [here](https://github.com/Canardoux/tau/issues/710)

Comment: Have you found solution, I am experiencing the similar situation?

Comment: here you can find what is the issue about it
https://github.com/Canardoux/flutter_sound/issues/710